# Custom compound field type with taxonomy term

Tags: entities, 8

I'm trying to create a custom compound field with 2 fields types, using Fields API.

So far, I have something like 'telephone' core module, that store just one string, but I can't even start to add taxonomy field (entity_reference field type) to compound my custom field.

I searched for a hint on core, but no success. Any hints are appreciated.

Drupal 8.0.5.

Comment: Quick idea: did you have a look at [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module bundle? I'm not sure if your issue is directly covered, and if field examples is provided (can't check now), but it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @AramBoyajyan I already checked there, it was my starting point. The main issue is add a taxonomy term as a field.